# box around theorem statement

Tags: packages, theorems, framed

Is there an easy way to put a box around a theorem in `LaTeX`? For example to state an important theorem.

I tried using page 20 of the `ntheorem` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf),
but I do not know how to use the package.

Comment: `ntheorem` uses `pstricks` to shade theorem. So you have to compile via `latex-ps-pdf` or `xelatex`. -- Maybe the package `framed` is helpful.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `\newmdtheoremenv` from the [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdtheoremenv{theo}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want to frame some theorems, then you can define a new environment using the `mdframed` environment and some previously defined theorem-like environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{ftheo}
  {\begin{mdframed}\begin{theo}}
  {\end{theo}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{ftheo}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{ftheo}

\begin{theo}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort.For some reason I don't get the whole box: I miss the bottom and left line.

Comment: @Nadori are you sure it's not only a viewer issue?

Comment: @Gonzalo: How do you mean?

But if I replace the theorem I get all the sides of the box except the left side.

Comment: @Nadori: some viewers don't show some lines, but zooming in or printing the document you can check that they effectively are there.

Comment: Lol, if I zoom in my pdf file I can see them indeed.
So when I print, this problem will not occur?

Comment: @Nadori: No there are no problems ;-)

Comment: @Nadori: I noticed that you've received some good answers to your other questions, but you haven't accepted any of them. Please consider marking those answers that you consider to be the best as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: how can i get rid of the enumeration?

Comment: when I have two md theorem environments it doesn't leave a gap it joins the 2 boxes and seperates them by a line

Answer (score 44):

I don't know if the `tcolorbox` package was available at the time that the question was asked, but here's a small example taken directly from the documentation:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{My Theorem}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
  This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
  in this example, prefixed with the section number. This theorem is numbered with
  \ref{th:theoexample} and is given on page \pageref{th:theoexample}.
\end{mytheo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! How could you get rid of the numbering?

Comment: Normally you add * to get rid of numbering in Latex, here I use \begin{mytheo*}.. \end{mytheo*} to get rid of the numbering.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a minimum working example (MWE) of how one can use the `ntheorem` and `framed` packages to draw a rectangular frame around a theorem environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed} % or, "mdframed"
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\newframedtheorem{frm-thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frm-thm}[Pythagoras]
Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ denote the lengths of the sides of a \emph{right 
triangle}, i.e., of a triangle with one angle equal to $90^\circ$. 
Without loss of generality assume that $a\le b<c$. Then
\[ a^2+b^2=c^2. \]
\end{frm-thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Check the user guides of the `framed` and `mdframed` packages for available options for setting the style of the frame.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how you can put some colour into your Theorems using `ntheorem` combined with `PSTricks`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

% framed theorem, red background
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
      \psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{mytheorem}{Special Theorem}

% framed theorem, gradient shading
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
      \psshadowbox[fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red,gradend=yellow,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{myfancytheorem}{Sunset special theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}
\lipsum[1] 
\end{mytheorem}

\begin{myfancytheorem}
 \lipsum[1]
\end{myfancytheorem}

\end{document}
```

Either run the above code with

```
latex myfile.tex
dvips myfile.dvi
ps2pdf myfile.ps
```

or

```
xelatex myfile.tex
```

If you want to run it with `pdflatex` then add the option `pdf` to the `pstricks` load

```
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
```

and compile with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools?lang=en), it should be noted that it can render boxed theorems per se. Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheorem[
  shaded={rulecolor=black, rulewidth=1pt, bgcolor=magenta},
  name=Theorem,
]{thmboxed}

\begin{document}

\begin{thmboxed}
\lipsum[1]
\end{thmboxed}

\end{document}
```

renders as

[image: this]

Comment: how do you suppress the theorem 1 in the title?

Comment: @DavidWarrenKatz what are you trying to achieve? Just a colored box with floating text inside? While it's possible to misuse `thmtools` for that by e.g. setting `headformat` and `headpunct` to `\@empty` in the custom theorem style, a better solution would be using boxes, e.g. a `\coloredbox` around a `\minipage`.