# How does one framebox a proof?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to frame box a proof I have written

For instance

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\framebox{ 

\emph{Proof} \\

 \text{content of proof goes here}

 }


 \end{document}
```

But the \ does absolutely nothing. All the text is squeezed together in the box

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do. Also, it would be helpful if you posted a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: have you seen [box around theorem statement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36278)

Comment: @PeterGrill, that's exactly what I have. There are no packages needed for frame box

Comment: @jak maybe not, but the code is not compilable.

Comment: If you use the `amsmath` package your proofs will look like proper proofs. As suggested by others, it is not clear why you would want to box frame your proofs. You should make this clearer. I guess you want to frame them for some presentation. If that's the case, then I suggest you use the `beamer` package, which will automatically do this for you. It comes with several styles for different kinds of frames/boxes and different colours for the forground and background of the frames.

Answer (score 4):

The answers provided at [box around theorem statement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36278) by cmhughes should be useful. This is a slightly different layout which is taken and modified from the `mdframed` documentation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{proofstyle}{%
linecolor=red,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
frametitlerule=true,%
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=white, right color=blue!20}}},
frametitlerulecolor=green!60,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
}
\mdtheorem[style=proofstyle]{proof}{Proof}
 %% \mdtheorem[style=proofstyle]{proof}{\itshape Proof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[Some heading]
content of proof goes here
\end{proof}

\bigskip
\begin{proof*}%%[Some heading]
content of proof goes here
\end{proof*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

To remove colors, just comment out some lines like:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{proofstyle}{%
%linecolor=red,
middlelinewidth=1pt,%
frametitlerule=true,%
%apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
%shade,left color=white, right color=blue!20}}},
%frametitlerulecolor=green!60,
frametitlerulewidth=.5pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to add an example of where all the colors and some of the decorations removed...? It's too colorful for me

Comment: @jak Please see the edit.

Comment: How does one remove that double box and the line that precedes the content? I really don't need anything that fancy

Comment: @jak: Put `frametitlerule=false,%` instead of `true`.

Comment: This is probably a little late, but upon using just regular \mdframe, I've notice the preview pdf compiled by latex and the actual pdf differ a lot. In the actual pdf, some frames were cut off