# Add vertical space before and after framed-theorem environments

Tags: spacing, theorems, mdframed

I want my theorem-like environments to be framed, as it's an effective way of making them stand out from the main text.

According to [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36280/21891) to the question [box around theorem statement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36278/box-around-theorem-statement), the `\newmdtheoremenv` command from the `mdframed` package is the way to go.

However, I find that vertical space before and after such framed-theorem environments is lacking (see below). I looked into the `mdframed` documentation but did not find anything to fix this.

Did I miss something in the documentation?

How would you fix this in an easy and efficient (automatic) way?

Is a package other than `mdframed` more appropriate for framed-theorem environments?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv{assum}{Assumption}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Fluid mechanics}

\section{Fields}

The following fields are of particular interest:
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\rho$: fluid density (time-dependent scalar field);
    \item $p_{\text{tot}}$: total pressure in the fluid (time-dependent scalar field);
    \item $v$: velocity of the fluid parcels (time-dependent vector field).
\end{itemize}    

\begin{assum}[Differentiability of tensor fields]
    \label{assum:differentiability}
    All tensor fields of interest are differentiable (weakly, at least).
\end{assum}

Assumption~\ref{assum:differentiability} blah blah

\subsubsection{Mass-continuity equation}

The mass-continuity equation is derived from the principle of conservation of mass:
\begin{assum}[Conservation of mass]
    \label{assum:conservation_of_mass}
    Fluid density $\rho$ is a conserved quantity within fluid parcels:
if $V_{\text{fp}}(t)$ delimits a region of space occupied by a fluid parcel
at time $t$, then
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{\mathrm{d}\phantom{t}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\iiint_{ V_{\text{fp}}(t)} \rho \, \mathrm{d}V = 0\,.
    \end{equation}
\end{assum}
blablah

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you missed that you can pass options to the environment; in particular you can use `skipabove=<length>`, `skipbelow=<length>`:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep]{assum}{Assumption}[chapter]
```

Your example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep]{assum}{Assumption}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Fluid mechanics}

\section{Fields}

The following fields are of particular interest:
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\rho$: fluid density (time-dependent scalar field);
    \item $p_{\text{tot}}$: total pressure in the fluid (time-dependent scalar field);
    \item $v$: velocity of the fluid parcels (time-dependent vector field).
\end{itemize}    

\begin{assum}[Differentiability of tensor fields]
    \label{assum:differentiability}
    All tensor fields of interest are differentiable (weakly, at least).
\end{assum}

Assumption~\ref{assum:differentiability} blah blah

\subsubsection{Mass-continuity equation}

The mass-continuity equation is derived from the principle of conservation of mass:
\begin{assum}[Conservation of mass]
    \label{assum:conservation_of_mass}
    Fluid density $\rho$ is a conserved quantity within fluid parcels: if $V_{\text{fp}}(t)$ delimits a region of space occupied by a fluid parcel at time $t$, then
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{\mathrm{d}\phantom{t}}{\mathrm{d}t} \iiint_{ V_{\text{fp}}(t)} \rho \, \mathrm{d}V = 0\,.
    \end{equation}
\end{assum}
blablah

\end{document}
```

[image]

This answers your two first questions; regarding the third one, if your frames must allow page breaks, the possibilities are basically `mdframed` or  [`framed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed); this  question compares them: [framed or mdframed? (Pros/Cons)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71554/3954).

Comment: @Jubobs You're welcome! I updated my answer answering your third question. Let me see if I can find the question I am talking about.

Comment: @Jubobs found it! Link provided!